# Correct gzip file format?

Tags: google-chrome, hex, gzip

I was submitting a job application, after research and a well thought out reply that was made on multiple questions, I clicked submit.  Then the page asked me to re-input my login data, I pray it would 1. remember my form data or 2. Allow the back button to work, but no. Fun times! God damn whoever developed that page.

I have spent some time reading about how to resurrect the form data from Chrome from [here](http://ondailybasis.com/blog/2012/09/21/read-content-encoding-gzip-data-from-captured-stream/) and [here](http://www.frozax.com/blog/2011/05/recover-file-google-chrome-cache-gzipped/).

I was able to do my regex to pull out the hex from the cached file, but it says that it is corrupted when I go to decompress it.

So my questions is how should the hex be?

Here is the first line, should it have two whitespaces at the end?

```
1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 ed bd 07 60 1c 49  <--- here?
```

And what about the end?

```
13 fe <-- what amount of whitespace should be here?
```

I found a post on here that stated what the file should end in and it was not the same. So I not sure where else I can go with this.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "when I go to decompress it"?  Are you converting the hex to binary first?  White space in between hex digits is immaterial.  The data you have, as far as you have provided it, is a valid gzip stream once converted to binary.

Comment: ok. The tutorials said to grab the hex and then decompress that. What should I be doing here? – As no matter what I have tried gzip still states: "not in gzip format[. But the cache says it is: "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Encoding: gzip"

Comment: Convert the hex to binary.

Comment: "binary.gz: not in gzip format". Same message

Comment: Then you did not properly do the conversion.  You would not get that error if the first two bytes of the file are 1f 8b.

Comment: Can you please outline how I should do this? I am on mac what tools should I use. I am starting with a chrome cache, where I just copy and paste the file code. Then I use a regex to grab all the hex (the first and last line of which are pasted above). Where/How do you recommend doing the hex->bin conversion?

Comment: I have since downloaded srecord and ran "srec_cat convert.hex -binary -o output.gz" and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74771/discussion-between-nate-uni-and-mark-adler).

Comment: Tried this as suggested:
$ xxd -r -p convert.hex > convert.gz 
$ gzip -d convert.gz 
gzip: convert.gz: unexpected end of file 
gzip: convert.gz: uncompress failed
Surely after all this the file must be corrupted?